# Self teaching Javascript and can't correct this code

Tags: javascript

It's mean to count up to the defined limit of 100, but can't determine where it's breaking. I've been using jsfiddle.net to test. Can someone help?

```
function cCounts (num) { 
var limit = 100;
   while (num != limit) {
       num++
} 
return (num);
}
   
   }
   var result = cCounts(0);
```

Comment: Your while loop exits only if `num` reaches `100`. Inside the body you reset `num` to `10` when it reaches `95` though, hence you get an infinite loop. Remove the `if` and it'll work. BTW, `cCounts` will always return `limit`, so you don't need the `return`. You also (syntactically) don't need the brackets around `(num)`.

Comment: There are quite a few wrong things with your code. As mentioned before you don't have valid code due to the extra curly bracket. You are also using equality operators (`==`, `!=`) instead of the correct identity operators (`===`, `!==`). And you have an infinite loop in that code.
I don't really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @LMD Ok. I am trying to count from 0 to 100. I am removing the `if` statement (I believe that was leftover by mistake), the `return` statement, and the extra curly bracket so the code now looks like this....
`
function cCounts (num) { 
var limit = 100;
   while (num != limit) {
       num++
} 
}
   
   }
   var result = cCounts(0);
`

Comment: @no_credo You still have an extra curly brace, so the code stil fails. If I remove it and then try to run the code, the function returns `100`, which I am assuming is the intended behavior. What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

First I wanted to show you an example of your code with more standard whitespace.

```js
function cCounts (num) {
  var limit = 100;
  while (num != limit) {
    num++
    if (num == 95) {
      num = 10;
    }
  } 
}
 return (num);
}
var result = cCounts(0);
```

Maybe from here you can see, your return statement is outside the function and you have a extra trailing curly bracket.

Beyond that, if you look at the logic of what your function does, inside your loop, whenever `num` is 95, you reset it to 10, but the loop would continue, leaving the possibility for an infinite loop whenever `num` is passed as less than 95.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this in replit and modified it to not only be syntactically correct, but also probably more efficient and work to what it looks like you are trying to accomplish.

```
function aCounts(num) {
  let limit = 100;
  for (; num !== limit;) {
    if (num === 95) {
      num = 10;
    }
    num++;
    console.log(num);
  }
  
}

var result = aCounts(0);
```

What I've done is change it to a `for` loop, and kept your core. It seems that the reset back to 10 at 95 is essentail, so I've kept that. However, if you could more clearly define your goal with that `if` statement, I could remove that if needed. I've also gone ahead and updated it to ES6 syntax.